# Why do these three sorting functions have such different runtimes?

Tags: c++, sorting, optimization

I implemented Insertion Sort in C++ in 3 different ways. One uses basic C arrays, one uses vectors, and one uses iterators:

```
void insertionsort_array(int *arr, size_t length)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        for (int k = i; k > 0 && arr[k] < arr[k-1]; k--)
            swap(arr[k], arr[k-1]);
}

template<typename T>
void insertionsort_vector(vector<T>& arr)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
        for (int k = i; k > 0 && arr[k] < arr[k-1]; k--)
            swap(arr[k], arr[k-1]);
}

template<class IterType>
void insertionsort_iterator(IterType iter, IterType end)
{
    for (IterType edge = iter + 1; edge != end; ++edge) 
        for (IterType ptr = edge; ptr != iter && *ptr < *(ptr-1); --ptr) 
            swap(*ptr, *(ptr-1));
}
```

I would expect the running times for these functions to differ by some constant. However, that is not the case (timings with GCC -O0):

```
// array
Sorting 1000000 lists of length 10:    2605531 usec
Sorting   50000 lists of length 100:   1268442 usec
Sorting     500 lists of length 1000:   787731 usec
Sorting       5 lists of length 10000:  759133 usec

// vector
Sorting 1000000 lists of length 10:    2888354 usec
Sorting   50000 lists of length 100:   2031675 usec
Sorting     500 lists of length 1000:  1604312 usec
Sorting       5 lists of length 10000: 1603279 usec

// iterator
Sorting 1000000 lists of length 10:    3003877 usec
Sorting   50000 lists of length 100:   4150561 usec
Sorting     500 lists of length 1000:  3829943 usec
Sorting       5 lists of length 10000: 3766683 usec
```

For lists of length 10 they all have about the same performance, but for arrays with length 10, iterators are nearly five times worse than C arrays. How can this be?

Edit: I re-tested it using -O3 and the effect seemed to disappear. It's good to know that I can avoid this problem using compiler optimization, but I still would like to understand this strange behavior that occurs at -O0.

```
// array
Sorting 1000000 lists of length 10:    802136 usec
Sorting   50000 lists of length 100:   300472 usec
Sorting     500 lists of length 1000:  185330 usec
Sorting       5 lists of length 10000: 179851 usec

// vector
Sorting 1000000 lists of length 10:    955003 usec
Sorting   50000 lists of length 100:   302232 usec
Sorting     500 lists of length 1000:  185034 usec
Sorting       5 lists of length 10000: 181459 usec


// iterator
Sorting 1000000 lists of length 10:    811077 usec
Sorting   50000 lists of length 100:   230852 usec
Sorting     500 lists of length 1000:  112885 usec
Sorting       5 lists of length 10000: 105739 usec
```

I compiled in GCC with either -O0 or -O3 and used no other compiler flags.

Comment: Post your benchmark code. And also tell us, is it Debug or Release build? Or, in GCC, have you used optimizations flag such as `-O4`?

Comment: Are optimizations turned on?

Comment: You didn't turn on optimizations, so the first set of benchmarks is moot. The second set of benchmarks seems normal to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no optimizations, the biggest difference probably comes from calling functions like `operator[]`. When functions are called [there is a lot that happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144993/how-much-overhead-is-there-in-calling-a-function-in-c) which causes overhead, and is especially significant when called in loops. However, with optimizations turned on, all these function calls are [inlined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) which is why you see the difference disappear. Note that any compiler nowadays should give you almost equivalent performance whether you use `std::vector` or a plain array.