# Is it ok to move code that will run only once into a function?

Tags: c#, c++, function, coding-style

Considering that my program has to perform a certain set of actions based on a condition, and this set of actions is described in 20-30 lines of code, should I keep it within the conditional (an `if` block, part of the `Main` function) or is it best practice to group it inside a function (called `PerformTheAction()` for example)?

I am interested in learning which is best practice regarding readability, design and performance, if it matters (I think it does in c++ at least).

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. If you have actual code that you want to ask this question about, consider posting to the Code Review site.

Comment: You can learn a lot for good coding practices and design here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this has been put on hold as being opinion-based, but it is definitely not opinion-based. There is a clear agreement among software engineering experts that functions should be as short as possible. So the answer is yes, put the code in its own function. The reasons are given here: https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/the-real-benefits-of-short-methods/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability, it is better to put it in a separate function. 
[How much overhead is there in calling a function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144993/how-much-overhead-is-there-in-calling-a-function-in-c) 
In the link they have mentioned how there is an overhead in calling a function. Though most compilers are smart enough to make it inline themselves, I'd recommend you make it an inline function explicitly.