# Does the Visual Studio sampling profiler have an assembly-level view?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, profiling

The Visual Studio 2015 sampling profiler<sup>1</sup> shows the collected results at the source level. Sometimes it is useful to see the collected samples directly at the assembly level. It is likely this data exists (since sampling is inherently an assembly-level operation) - but can it actually be *displayed* in Visual Studio?

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the default profiling that you're probably using if you never chose anything different.

Comment: It should be able to. VS has an assembly language window. If an instruction's address appears on some call stacks, why can't that instruction be shown? The fraction of all call stack samples that contain that address is a direct measure of its inclusive time percent. I bet they haven't thought of it, or maybe they did but they pooh-poohed it.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - just to be sure I'm parsing the "should" part of your comment correctly, what you are saying is that "It would have been a good/easy idea to do this" and not "I think it is already available in VS", right?

Comment: I guess I'm saying it would be easy to do, but that's no assurance they did it, and I don't know if they did. (You might know that I take a dim view of most profilers, the exception being Zoom from Rotate Right, though I'm not sure they're still in business. I've expounded enough on this to be considered a curmudgeon :)